# Unable to execute function

Tags: f#

I am just not getting F#.

Specifically, I am unable to step into the following code:

```
let count = hand |> getHandCount
```

It's like that entire line is just being ignored in the debugger.

Here's the test:

```
[<Test>]
let ``get card count`` () =

    let hand, deckRemaining = deal (shuffle deck)
    let count = hand |> getHandCount

    count |> should be (greaterThan 0)
```

Here's the code:

```
type Suit = | Spades| Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts

type Face = | Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face:Face; Suit:Suit}

type Deal = | Hand of Card * Card
            | Hit of Card

let getCount (hand:Card list) =
    let getFaceValue = function
        | Two -> 2
        | Three -> 3
        | Four -> 4
        | Five -> 5
        | Six -> 6
        | Seven -> 7
        | Eight -> 8
        | Nine -> 9
        | Ten -> 10
        | Jack -> 10
        | Queen -> 10
        | King -> 10
        | Ace -> 11

    hand |> List.sumBy (fun c -> getFaceValue c.Face)

let getHandCount hand = function
    | Some(card1, card2) -> [card1; card2] |> getCount
    | None -> 0
```

What important lesson am I missing now?

Comment: "line ignored in the debugger" is a common symptom for "unused code thrown away by the compiler". could that be the reason? what happens if you try to print out `count`?

Comment: General debugging tip: The debugger was designed first for statement oriented  languages, where each step is usually a statement. This doesn't translate neatly to expression oriented languages where you go through many logical steps in a single nested (or pipelined) expression. I found it helps to use **step into** a lot more in F#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you write a *pattern matching function*, e.g.:

```
let f = function
    |Case1 -> // something
    |Case2 -> // something else
```

You are writing the equivalent of:

```
let f = fun arg ->
    match arg with
    |Case1 -> // something
    |Case2 -> // something else
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233242.aspx

Your `getHandCount` function therefore takes an argument `hand` *and* takes an argument from the implicit lambda which you are not supplying.  So just remove the argument `hand` from your function.

```
let getHandCount = function
    | Some(card1, card2) -> [card1; card2] |> getCount
    | None -> 0
```

Comment: My hero! once again. =)

Answer (score 3):

When you have

```
let getHandCount hand = function
    | Some(card1, card2) -> [card1; card2] |> getCount
    | None -> 0
```

if you paste it into the interactive you get

```
val getHandCount : hand:'a -> _arg1:(Card * Card) option -> int
```

This tells you that the `hand` argument is essentially ignored and `gethandCount` returns a function

realistically I am surprised the code even compiles